# JQ: How to simplify an object so that the name strings stay in place, and a child object simplifies to a single value?

Tags: shell, jq

Suppose a json exists:

```
{
  "foo": {
     "descr": "this is hard to ask",
     "value": "but it must be easy to answer"
  }
}
```

And the goal is:

```
cat foo.json | jq '<something>'
{
  "foo": "but it must be easy to answer"
}
```

Is there a way to do this simply in jq?

Comment: "How do I search for my questions [without inline tags]?" - Probably better asked on meta as I imagine it's going to get edited out here in short order, but you can search on tags like `user:3834415 [jq]`. It's a pretty long-standing consensus here that titles shouldn't redundantly duplicate tags.

Comment: @Weeble I've been doing it for years.

Comment: @Weeble not really sure consensus applies to individual questions, unless the consensus has the power and will to write them.

Comment: Maybe I should have said "prevailing opinion" rather than "consensus"? I just know it's very common to make such edits and generally seems to be endorsed by the community. E.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303606/is-it-ok-to-systematically-edit-the-questions-titles-like-this and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253028/why-is-removing-tags-from-the-title-suggested-so-often I don't really have strong feelings on the policy. I saw your comment and thought you might find the search tip helpful.

Comment: @Weeble thanks I get it -- everyone on here regularly is busting their chops, and we care.  I'll pick up the search habit.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility:

```
.foo |= .value
```

Comment: Since this got more upvotes then the build-in `map_values`. Are there any advantages compared to `map_values`?

Comment: @0stone0 - The functionality is quite different: one is like a surgical knife, the other like a sledgehammer. Which is more appropriate depends on the detailed functional requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The answer here is:

```
jq 'map_values(.value)'
```

And I got it from reading the docs... which wasn't ideal, but did pay off.

Comment: @0stone0 adding this to the comments so that it is here, on this thread.  Here is 0stone0's answer, which shows off what map can do/how it works, here it is: `jq 'to_entries | map({ (.key): .value.value }) | add`